# get view from service

Tags: android, unicode, android-edittext

I need to get current view (from other application) ID from my service, because I can't send unicode (Android's limitation) character to other app's EditText, without set EditText text directly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can not get the view directly through the service, but I have the trick.
First you declare

```
public static View view;
```

in your MainActivity.class
then initialze it by

```
view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);//the root view
```

then in your service, you can call MainActivity.view
hope this help